# Codewars Persistence method with recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I finished a Kata on Codewars, which is the multiplicative persistence method. For those who aren't aware of the challenge, it goes as follows:

The function takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit. For example:

```
 persistence(39) === 3 // because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
                   // and 4 has only one digit

 persistence(999) === 4 // because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,
                    // 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2

 persistence(4) === 0 // because 4 is already a one-digit number
```

My solution, which works, uses two while loops (below). I am now attempting to write the method using recursion. However, I see that I may run into threading issues (since I need to return the number of times I am multiplying the digits). Is it possible to use recursion? If so, how?

This is my code using iteration:

```java
public static int persistence(long n) {
    int count = 0;
    if(n < 10) return count;
    long num = 1;

    while(n >= 10) {
      while(n != 0) {
        num*=(n % 10);
        n/=10;
      } 
      n = num;
      num = 1;
      count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

As of now, I only know that:

1. The base case would be

   ```
     if(n < 10) return 0;
   ```

   This is if n is a single digit.

The recursive case is what I am stuck in. Thanks!

Comment: "threading issues" : How? Is your code being run on parallel threads? If yes, Can you give a context of how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily eliminate the outer loop with recursion:

```
public static int persistence(long n) {
    if(n < 10) return 0;
    long num = 1;
    while(n != 0) {
        num*=(n % 10);
        n/=10;
    } 
    if (num > 10) {
        return 1 + persistence (num);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
public static int persistence(long n) {
    if(n < 10) return 0;
    long num = 1;
    while(n != 0) {
        num*=(n % 10);
        n/=10;
    }
    return 1 + persistence (num);
}
```